# Renaming date variable to perform an intck to calculate day difference

Tags: sas

I have this dataset  and need to calculate the days' difference between each dose date per period. How do I label each period study date so I can carry out an intck to calculate the days' difference per subject (ptno)

[image: dataset]

Comment: Sounds like you want to calculate the difference in days between values of EX_STADT in adjacent observations when sorting by PTNO and PERIOD?  What value do you want on the first observation for a subject? Not sure what you mean by "label".

Comment: So I just want to confirm that the difference between each period for each subject is 7 days. I thought it would be best to label each date of each period e.g if period is 1 then ex-stdat= ex-stdat1, period= 2 then ex_stdat = ex_stdat2 etc.  Would ti be better to use a lag function?

Comment: You seem to be using "label" to mean create a new variable Variables have names. They can also have a descriptive label attached to them, but the name is what you need to use in code.  Whether it is useful to transform your table from tall to wide depends on what you are doing, but in general it will just make coding harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the DIF() function to calculate the change in value for your date variable.  SAS stores dates as number of days so the difference will be the number of days between the two observations.  You could then test if the difference is 7 days or not.

```
data want;
   set have;
   by ptno period;
   interval = dif(ex_stadt);
   if first.ptno then interval=0;
   seven_days = (interval = 7) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code of Tom works very well. I simulated the data set with a few rows based in
the sample showed above and it's OK.
Only thing absent is PROC SORT. If the data set is huge the log will exhibit an error.

```
proc sort data=have;
   by ptno period;
run;
```

Comment: Good thinking. I made sure to account for this.